# grep a specific strings in a Perl array

Tags: perl, grep

How to grep only multiple sets of five characters in any order in an array in a Perl program?

```
@arr2 = grep(/[BCRZ]+/, @arr1);
```

`@arr1` can contain

```
CRZBBZTCCBBRZ
FJDLSFJSLFJS
CRZBBZCCBBRZ
```

only the lines like the last should be taken

Comment: I don't understand why the first line should be excluded. And where are your *five* characters? Do you mean the string has to contain at least five of `BCRZ`?

Comment: I missed the 5th letter. Let's take some thing different from T like W. In this case, the 1st and 2nd should be discarded. Any set of 5, CBRZW in any order in any length is accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what is you want is lines that only contain the 5 chars and none others, then a regex like:

```
 /^[BRCZW]+$/
```

looks for strings containing one or more of your 5-character set, but containing no other characters. But it might be more efficient to us @carol's solution using grep(). Which uses a regex to determine if the string has any of the unwanted characters, and then rejects that line.

Comment: As I suggested in the comments below @Borodin's answer, this could be used in exactly the same way inside a `grep`. How were you suggesting it could be used instead?

Comment: I don't think your answer was in my feed when I typed mine. But yes, I am suggesting the same thing as you.

Answer (score 3):

I think this may do what you want. It rejects a string if it contains any character other than `CBRZW`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr1 = qw/ CRZBBZTCCBBRZ FJDLSFJSLFJS CRZBBZCCBBRZ /;

my @arr2 = grep { not /[^CBRZW]/ } @arr1;

print "$_\n" for @arr2;
```

**output**

```
CRZBBZCCBBRZ
```

Comment: but it seems that with "not", it holds any thing except BCRZ, no? which is the opposite of what I want

Comment: @carol this is a double negative - there's the `not` _and_ the `^` in the character class. Another way you could do this is with `grep { /^[BCRZ]+$/ } @arr1;` - one or more characters from that class between the start and end of the string.

Comment: @carol: Tom is correct. As I wrote, the code  rejects a string if it contains any character *other than* `CBRZW`. Also, the code produces the output that you requested.